# How to determine tiered tax rate with a concise snippet?

Tags: php, integer-arithmetic, calculation, tax

I am trying to create a tiered tax calculator.

The user enters an amount, say `500,000`

From that amount, I then have the following tiers that tax is charged as follows:

```
        0 -   125,000 = 0%
  125,001 -   250,000 = 2%
  250,001 -   925,000 = 5%
  925,001 - 1,500,000 = 10%
1,500,001 -   or more = 12%
```

So no tax on the first `125,000`, then `2%` on the next `124,999` and so on.

I can come up with long winded calculations with far too many lines of code.  I am sure there is a relatively simple way to do this, so I am bowing to the greater knowledge of folks here to find a more concise method.

Comment: I'm interested to see if I can come up with something more concise, but need to have something to compare it to!

Comment: What is the expected result when the user enters 130,000? I would expect `125,000 * 0.00 + (130,000 - 125,000) * .02 = 100`.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, nice challenge though. I'm sorry, I couldn't really come up with a smart way, but if you are in dire need I created this little function;

```
function calculator($value) {

    if(!is_int($value) && !is_double($value))
        return;

    if($value > 1500000)
        $value = $value - ($value*0.12);

    elseif($value > 925000)
        $value = $value - ($value*0.10);

    elseif($value > 250000)
        $value = $value - ($value*0.05);

    elseif($value > 125000)
        $value = $value - ($value*0.02);

    return $value;

}
```

You just feed it with a value (int or double) and it will return the calculated value. Be aware you can't use `,` (comma) though.

Edit: Changed to logic a little.

Answer (score 1):

This won't do any number validation or currency formatting, but it does condense the snippet fairly well.  I am also not sure which figure you wanted as a result, so I am returning three values: the rate, the amount of tax, and the price less the tax.

Rather than a block of if/else statements, I've elected to use array functions. ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/59428effa7fd8bfddf16ad1992f476905863aa53))

Method #1: 2-lines and a return

```
function tax($value) {
    $tiers=['.12'=>1500000,'.1'=>925000,'.05'=>250000,'.02'=>125000,'0'=>0];
    $rate=key(array_filter($tiers,function($threshold)use($value){return $value>$threshold;}));
    return [$rate,$value*$rate,$value-$value*$rate];
}
```

Method #2: 4-lines and a return, but more efficient

```
function tax($value) {
    $tiers=['.12'=>1500000,'.1'=>925000,'.05'=>250000,'.02'=>125000,'0'=>0];
    foreach($tiers as $rate=>$threshold){
        if($value>$threshold){break;}  // $rate will be preserved outside of the loop
    }
    return [$rate,$value*$rate,$value-$value*$rate];
}
```

Calling the function like this: `var_export(tax(126999));` will output:

```
array (
  0 => '.12',
  1 => 1523988.0,
  2 => 11175912.0,
)
```

---

Since you are placing "code brevity" ahead of "code efficiency", I would recommend Method #1.  Because this task is so small/light, I don't think anyone will notice any gains via micro-optimization.

p.s. If you are not doing this multiple times in the same script and/or don't want a function call, you can declare `$rate` just by using this:

```
$tiers=['.12'=>1500000,'.1'=>925000,'.05'=>250000,'.02'=>125000,'0'=>0];
$rate=key(array_filter($tiers,function($threshold)use($value){return $value>$threshold;}));
```

or

```
$tiers=['.12'=>1500000,'.1'=>925000,'.05'=>250000,'.02'=>125000,'0'=>0];
foreach($tiers as $rate=>$threshold){
    if($value>$threshold){break;}
}
```